# Using OSC with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, osc

I need to create a test server in NodeJS that supports OSC over UDP. After a quick search there seems to be a lot of options. Can anyone recommend a module for OSC in NodeJS?

Answer (score 5):

Colin Clark's osc.js is great. https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js/tree/master

There is a set of examples at https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js-examples

It is a full implementation of the OSC specification and provides node.js, browser, chrome app, and also compatibility with IP over serial if you are working with microcontrollers.